# Firebase User Profile

Tags: firebase, emberfire

I'm just getting started on creating a user signup and user profile login flow. For some background, each user will be able to sign up and apart of the signup process, fill out their profile (for example purposes, let's say they have to fill out: address, phone, city).

Am I on the right track in thinking that I should utilize a 'user' model? Since firebase can handle all the authentication does that mean the user model will not need a belongsTo('user')?

For Firebase security rules, how would I go about setting this up? A user can only view and edit their own profile(stored in user model).

Does anyone have any example projects of this sort of flow?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah you need to make a collection called ```userProfileInfo``` or something like that and store documents that contain extra user info (telephone, address, etc...). The main ```User``` collection can only store email/password (or other data depending on the login authentication flow you are using).

Comment: @Supertecnoboff it seems like that collection can still be named 'user.' Is that correct?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but even if it works, I wouldn't recommend having two collections with the same name. That will surely lead to confusion/bugs at some point during development.

Comment: Sure, good point.